# Mobile Specific Views / Device Detection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the .NET Core docs there is a page titled "Building Mobile Specific Views" but is under construction: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/mobile.html.

Does anyone have some insight on building mobile views or successfully doing device detection?

Comment: In the old ASP.NET MVC Framework there used to be built-in detection where you could name you views like "MyView.cshtml" and "MyView.iOS.cshtml" or similar and get them served appriately based on their user agents. But this practice is pretty discouraged nowadays. It's better to make an responsive design which works on all devices. Look for "responsive design bootstrap" for example. Bootstrap is originally developed by Twitter to realize a responsive design

Comment: Probably @Tseng is right here, but just FYI (as I do not about responsive design :-))...if you want to still follow the approach of "MyView.cshtml" and "MyView.iOS.cshtml", then you can take a look at how MVC's `LanguageViewLocationExpander` works as this seems something similar...

Comment: @Tseng If you want to add you comment as an Answer, I will mark that as accepted as it's what everyone is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serving specific views based on the browser's user-agent is an outdated concept as it do not sufficiently says much about the capabilities of the device. For example, iPhone and iPad come in different screen sizes and even mobile browsers allow to change the user-agent.

The new concept is called Responsive Design where one creates a single page that fits and show/hides certain element based on the available screen width. One popular responsive deisgn CSS Framework is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), originally developed by Twitter and later open-sourced.

[Here](https://responsivedesign.is/examples/publishers/the-forecaster-interactive) is an example of responsive design. When you go to the [site](http://theforecaster-interactive.com) and change the width of your browser, the design updates as well from 3 to 2 to 1 column design with browser or mobile like navigation (with the Hamburger menu).

Comment: It is mostly true, but there are cases when we should send different DOM to phones for little screens, instead of just hide/show.

Comment: In some cases simple responsive design is not effective. In some cases this lead to really big website assets size which can lead to slow initial load. One more thing is JS - for most of modern sites having enourmous amount of JS code, but some content heavy sites (news aggregators, e-comerces), may no need to have all this type of content on mobile, so we could just erase it at server side.

Answer (score 1):

This feature actually was not implemented by microsoft. There is couple open discussions for this question:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4877
- https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/751

As a generic answer from them - use responsive web design and css media queries (which from my point of view is not perfect answer for team that claims himself for building general web framework).
There is a implementation for this feature exist as pull request - https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/4878.

Since this pull request seems to be forgotten, i extract this code into separate project which is available on
https://github.com/laskoviymishka/MvcDeviceDetector.

You may use this implementation (which is easy to add to exist MVC project) or implement this itself. This is pretty easy - you need just implement and reqister own `IViewLocationExpander` for that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handle in .Net Core using RazorViewEngineOptions

1) Create Service LocationExpanderService.cs

```
 public class LocationExpanderService : IViewLocationExpander
{

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context,
        IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        //replace the Views to MyViews..  

        var viewLocationsFinal = new List<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Values["viewCustom"]))
        {
            foreach (var viewLocation in viewLocations)
            {
                viewLocationsFinal.Add(viewLocation.Replace(".cshtml", ".mobile.cshtml"));
            }
        }
        viewLocationsFinal.AddRange(viewLocations);
        return viewLocationsFinal;
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

        var userAgent = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString().ToLower();
        var viewCustom = userAgent.Contains("android") || userAgent.Contains("iphone") ? "mobile" : "";
        context.Values["viewCustom"] = viewCustom;
    }
}
```

2) Configure services in startup.cs

```
  services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new LocationExpanderService());
        });
```

3) Create view with .mobile extension

```
Index.mobile.cshtml
```