# Detect mobile device in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an application which uses mobile views and desktop views as different html pages. Now I am moving that to Asp.Net core. I am not thinking about Bootstrap due to some technical reasons. I have to detect the request is from Mobile or not in StartUp to load respective Layout page. How can I achieve that ? Looking for something similar to IsMobileDevice. Already tried **MvcDeviceDetector 0.1.0-t00349acaa**. It didn't worked as I am using .net version 4.6.1.

Comment: There they suggest to use Bootstrap it seems. But as I said, I won't use it

Comment: please follow below link for the solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61575500/10137052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the manual method outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13086894/1419970

Or you can use this library: http://www.nuget.org/packages/51Degrees.mobi/3.2.10.3-beta

Both will do for you.

Comment: Unable to resolve '51Degrees.mobi (>= 3.2.9.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.

Comment: **Unable to resolve '51Degrees.mobi (>= 3.2.9.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'. ** This is the error I am getting when I tried 51degrees. It is not supporting .net version 4.6.1 I guess.

Comment: I guess it will give me a solution. Just I need to change the method to compact with .net core.

Answer (score 19):

I found great library. It's very easy to use. I am not sure is it 100% reliable, but it's covering all my cases.

Example:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {           
        private readonly IDevice device;   

        public HomeController(IDeviceResolver deviceResolver)
        {                
            this.device = deviceResolver.Device
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if(device.Type == DeviceType.Desktop)
            {
               //some logic
            }
            else if(device.Type == DeviceType.Mobile)
            {
               //some logic
            }
            else if(device.Type == DeviceType.Tablet)
            {
               //some logic
            }
        }
     }
```

[Device detection .NET CORE](https://github.com/wangkanai/Detection)

Thank you **Wangkanai**

Comment: Can we check device globally and not in each controller or action? Actually I wanted to render mobile views for mobile device and desktop views for desktop device

Comment: I think it can be done in middleware on the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution

```
     public static class Extentions
        {
            public static bool IsMobile(string userAgent)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
                    return false;
    //tablet
                if (Regex.IsMatch(userAgent, "(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobile))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    return true;
    //mobile
                const string mobileRegex =
                    "blackberry|iphone|mobile|windows ce|opera mini|htc|sony|palm|symbianos|ipad|ipod|blackberry|bada|kindle|symbian|sonyericsson|android|samsung|nokia|wap|motor";
    
                if (Regex.IsMatch(userAgent, mobileRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) return true;
   //not mobile 
                return false;
            }
        }
```

use:

```
var isMobile = Extentions.IsMobile(Context.Request.Headers["user-agent"].ToString());
```

Comment: Best solution I've found. No need to install any packages and troubleshoot class relation and proper usage. thx!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this free library [DeviceDetector.NET](https://github.com/totpero/DeviceDetector.NET).

This is a port of the popular PHP [device-detector](https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector) library to C#.

[Here](https://github.com/totpero/DeviceDetector.NET/blob/master/DeviceDetector.NET.Web/Controllers/HomeController.cs) is how to use it.

```
DeviceDetectorNET.DeviceDetector.SetVersionTruncation(VersionTruncation.VERSION_TRUNCATION_NONE); 
var userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
var result = DeviceDetectorNET.DeviceDetector.GetInfoFromUserAgent(userAgent);
var output = result.Success ? result.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") : "Unknown";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I use for my .NET6 project using middleware.
https://github.com/totpero/DeviceDetector.NET

```
using DeviceDetectorNET;
       
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
         var detector = new DeviceDetector(context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString());
         detector.SetCache(new DictionaryCache());
         detector.Parse();

        if (detector.IsMobile())
        {
            context.Items.Remove("isMobile");
            context.Items.Add("isMobile", true);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Items.Remove("isMobile");
            context.Items.Add("isMobile", false);
        }

        context.Items.Remove("DeviceName");
        context.Items.Add("DeviceName", detector.GetDeviceName());

        await next();

    });
}
```

Usage

```
  var deviceName = HttpContext.Items["DeviceName"].ToString();
  var isMobile = Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Items["isMobile"]);
```