# How to resolve mobile views in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In regular ASP.NET MVC we used `IDisplayMode` to implement a display mode provider and then configure it in `Global.asax.cs` file.
This was particularly useful because we'd have a view called `Index.cshtml` and another one `Index.Mobile.cshtml` and the provider would decide which view to resolve.

How can I achieve the same within ASP.NET Core? I've come across `IViewLocationExpander` interface which "is the right way to do things" (from [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/751)) with no further infomation. I also can't find any other resources about this.

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46552775/9020340

Comment: I’ve closed this question with a link to a related question that covers the question for AMP but is generally asking the same thing (how to switch views based on some logic, like what display mode previously allowed). The answer there shows how to use the view location expander.